# In Javascript is there equivalent to .apply that doesn't change the value of this?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, apply

Seems easy enough, i want to call a function with array of arguments. Sure, i can say `func.apply(this, ['some', 'arguments']);` but that will change the value of `this` inside `func`. Any idea how to do this without changing it?

Comment: Well, you can pass `null` as first argument. However, what should `this` refer to within `func` ?

Comment: The question is not enough clear. Please give more code.

Comment: Sounds like you're using `this` inside the function in a way that it's not supposed to be used.

Comment: Ok, i get it now. In my case i had a prototype function of an object, that i wanted to call with `.apply()`. I assumed that the function would somehow be tied to its object, so i didn't want to change it as apply does, but apparently there is no such connection and `apply()` simply deals with the function it is called upon.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that in ES6 you can also write:

```
func(...someArray)
```

Here `this` becomes `Window` inside `func`, which is of no use. But if you write:

```
obj.func(...someArray)
```

`this` in inside `func` will be `obj`.

This may be the feature i was looking for 5 years ago, but that was 5 years ago, so who remembers :)

Answer (score 30):

You cannot, **because of the way `this` works in JavaScript**. Read on:

Going by the ["Entering An Execution Context"](http://interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-10.html#a-10.2) section of the ECMAScript spec: when you call a function, the value of `this` is determined by what's to it's left (called the **activation object**) . Let's create a function called steve, and put him in an object:

```
function steve(){}
var obj = { method: steve };
```

…when we call steve as `obj.method()`, his `this` is `obj`, because `obj` was the activation object.

The tricky case is when *nothing* is to the left of a function call:

```
steve(); // Who am I ?!
```

There's *nothing* to the left of the function call — effectively, it's `null` — so the value of `this` is set to a default value of the global object (`window` in web browsers, `global` in Node.js, etc.).

So you are, in fact, setting a function's `this` every time you call it.

P.S. calling `steve.apply(null, [])` is equivalent to calling `steve()`.

Comment: With ES5, this isn't true. The value of this is undefined (not null), and this is not changed to the global object (this isn't actually true within with statements, but I'll ignore them for now). For both ES3 and ES5 engines, outside of with statements, `steve.apply(undefined, [])` and `steve()` are equivalent, though their behaviour differs between ES3 and ES5.

Comment: @gsnedders, thanks! What I found in the spec ([section 10.4.3](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_10.4.3)) describes `this` being set to the global object, and `null`/`undefined` being equivalent. Can you show me where the new behavior is described?

Comment: Love answers that reference the spec to provide context.

Comment: What happens when I want to invoke a function object that has already been binded to an object, without changing the 'this'? For instance, var handler = MyFunction.bind(myObject); Here I have created a function object already bound to myObject as the 'this' object; Now I want to call handler from another part of my code that doesnt even know the existense of myObject. handler.call(null, params) would destroy the this, no? What happens if I call it as handler.call(undefined, params)?

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis: A bound function should ignore the value of `this` it gets at call time. `this` will still be whatever you passed to `.bind()`.

Answer (score 4):

The value of `this` is no mystery when calling a function, depending on how it is called "normally" (without `call` or `apply`):

```
func(); // `this` is the global object, or undefined in ES5 strict mode
obj.func(); // `this` is `obj`
```

So to avoid "changing" the value of `this`, just pass in the correct value to `apply`, depending on how you would call it "normally":

```
func.apply(undefined, []); // global object, or undefined in ES5 strict mode
obj.func.apply(obj, []);
```

Comment: null doesn't work for the global object for browsers that implement ES5, as then "this" in the called function will be the null value.

Comment: @gsnedders, be careful when you say es5, because that is only true in strict mode.  Nonetheless, I've changed my answer to pass in undefined for optimal compatibility. cheers.

Comment: Hmm, the note under Function.prototype.apply turns out to be somewhat misleading if you follow the algorithm deeper… "The thisArg value is passed without modification as the this value. This is a change from Edition 3, where a undefined or null thisArg is replaced with the global object and ToObject is applied to all  other values and that result is passed as the this value."

Comment: @gsnedders, I don't understand what you mean by that. Care to explain?

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling a function alone, pass `null`.

```
func.apply(null, ['some', 'arguments']);
```

If you are calling a function that is a method of an object, pass that object.

```
var arr = [];
arr.push.apply(arr, ['some', 'arguments']);
```

In order to match a how [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this) works.

Answer (score 0):

What you want doesn't make much sense.

In the ecmascript standard `this` is defined this way:

> 11.1.1 The this Keyword  The this keyword evaluates to the value of the
>   ThisBinding of the current execution
>   context.

The thisBinding resolution for a functions execution context is specified this way:

> 10.4.3 Entering Function Code  The following steps are performed when
>   control enters the execution context
>   for function code contained in 
>   function object F, a caller provided
>   thisArg, and a caller provided
>   argumentsList:
>
> 1. If the function code is strict code, set the ThisBinding to thisArg.
> 2. Else if thisArg is null or undefined, set the ThisBinding to the
>      global object.
> 3. Else if Type(thisArg) is not Object, set the ThisBinding to
>      ToObject(thisArg).
> 4. Else set the ThisBinding to thisArg.
> 5. Let localEnv be the result of calling NewDeclarativeEnvironment 
>      passing the value of the [[Scope]]
>      internal  property of F as the
>      argument.
> 6. Set the LexicalEnvironment to localEnv.
> 7. Set the VariableEnvironment to localEnv.
> 8. Let code be the value of F’s [[Code]] internal property.
> 9. Perform Declaration Binding Instantiation using the function code
>      code and argumentList as described in 
>      10.5.

In other words: either you specify it or it is automatically set to the global object. It will never inherit the this binding from it's parent scope, so the only way to give the thisBindiong of the parent scope to it's children is either by

1. save it in a local variable in the parent scope like var `self = this`
2. inject it with call/apply like the code you gave in your question.