# What does undefined refer to in javascript function prototype

Tags: javascript, call, apply

In this code what does undefined mean? Without specifying undefined it says " my name is undefined and i am a undefined"

```js
(function(){
    'use strict';

    function theFunction(name, profession) {
        console.log("My name is " + name + " and I am a " + profession + " . ");
    }
    theFunction("John", "fireman");
    theFunction.apply(undefined,["ali", "Developer"]);
    theFunction.call(undefined, "sara", "doctor");
}());
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247060/in-javascript-is-there-equivalent-to-apply-that-doesnt-change-the-value-of-thi it's so you don't change the value of `this`.

Comment: _"Without specifying undefined it says " my name is undefined and i am a undefined""_ Where?

Comment: I think OP means, if he doesn't add `undefined` as the first parameter when using apply or call. The correct answer is below.

Answer (score 6):

My answer assumes that by `Without specifying undefined` you mean a call like that:

```
 theFunction.apply(["ali", "Developer"]);
```

When you use `call` or `apply`, the first parameter is the execution context (variable `this` inside `theFunction`). The two examples set it to `undefined`, so `this` inside `theFunction` will evaluate to `undefined`. For example:

```
function theFunction(name, profession) {
      console.log(this); // logs `undefined`
      console.log("My name is " + name + " and I am a " + profession + " . ");
}

theFunction.apply(undefined, ["ali", "Developer"]);
```

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706159/whats-the-benefit-of-binding-to-undefined-instead-of-null) the thread explaining why one would use `undefined` as execution context.

Now, to your question. If you omit `undefined` in your call is like that:

```
theFunction.apply(["ali", "Developer"]);
```

the execution context - `this` - is set to `["ali", "Developer"]`, and `name` and `profession` are evaluated as `undefined` since you only pass one parameter to `apply`, that is why you're getting `"My name is undefined and I am a undefined"`

`call` and `apply` are usually used when you want to change the execution context of the function. You're probably using `apply` to turn array of arguments into separate arguments. To do that, you need to set the same execution context as the one that would have been if you called the function without apply:

```
theFunction("John", "fireman"); // `this` points to `window`
theFunction.apply(this, ["John", "fireman"]); // `this` points to `window`
```

Comment: `this` is never used anywhere, and the code outputs not what the OP says it does.

Comment: I was gonna say, some code would explain more, but you beat me to it :)

Comment: OP does not use `theFunction.apply(["ali", "Developer"])` at `javascript` at Question. Though OP might have tried `theFunction()`

Comment: Okay, I now understand what "Without specifying undefined" meant. They posted the code with specifying undefined and questioned the result of not specifying undefined. This answer is correct then.

Comment: OP's example doesn't utilize the true meaning of call and apply (override `this`), it's exactly the same as simply calling the function directly.

Comment: @guest271314, well, I added assumption about how the function is called at the top of my answer. I based my answer on that assumption

Comment: @Maximus You could also extrapolate that OP tried `theFunction()`

Comment: @Maximus you assumed right, I could have written my question more clearly. Thank you for your help

Comment: @codeforfun, cool, if you think there's anything else I can add to make my answer acceptable, let me know

Comment: @timenomad, thanks for the suggestion, added that clarification at the bottom of the question

Comment: @codeforfun Consider updating Question to include all of the calls you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Though `theFunction()` is not included as one of the calls tried, `theFunction()` reproduces result described at Question

> Without specifying undefined it says " my name is undefined and i am a
>   undefined"

that is, to call `theFunction()` without passing parameters; which would be expected result where `name` and `profession` are `undefined` within function body when `theFunction` is called.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function theFunction(name, profession) {
    console.log("My name is " + name + " and I am a " + profession + " . ");
  }
  theFunction(); // logs result described at Question
  theFunction("John", "fireman");
  theFunction.apply(undefined, ["ali", "Developer"]);
  theFunction.call(undefined, "sara", "doctor");

}());
```

Comment: this call `theFunction.apply(["ali", "Developer"]);` would produce the result the OP gets `My name is undefined and I am a undefined . `

Comment: @Maximus Edited Answer; though both `theFunction()` and `theFunction.apply(["ali", "Developer"])` are not included as what OP actually tried. None of the listed calls at Question return result described at Question.

Comment: you're right. Your assumption is as possible as mine. Anyways, I upvoted your answer since it shows the other possible alternative.